# How to uninstall one site of a multi-site?

Tags: multi-sites

Things are bit messed up in one of my sites, partly because of modules that did not clean up after themselves when I disabled them and partly because I tried to clean up for them, which of course, only partially worked.

So I want to remove this site and start it over again with a fresh install. But I don't see anything on how to uninstall or remove a site.

(This is a development environment, of course!)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to it as long as they have separate databases:

1. Deactivate the virtualhost pointing at your site and restart apache
2. Backup and delete the database for that site
3. Backup and delete the site folder inside `Drupal_root/sites` where Drupal_root is your core Drupal repository

Then rebuild however you please.